# Makefile without explicit targets

Tags: makefile

If I have a set of files *.foo that are "compiled" to a set of *.bar using a `foo2bar some.foo` "compiler" I can write a Makefile like this:

```
  %.bar: %.foo
    <tab>foo2bar $<
```

However if there are no *.bar yet, I can't just type something like `make all` and have all the *.bar produced.

How do I tell make to create all missing targets that match *.bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you are using GNU make (which you seem to be since you used the %-notation already):

```
all: $(patsubst %.foo,%.bar,$(wildcard *.foo))
```

Comment: BSD make has % (at least it did on FreeBSD last time I checked).